# usage id of F1,F2,F3,F4... when holding Fn

Tags: memory, hex, allocation, hid

What is usage id (hex code) of F1,F2,F3... when holding Fn.
Apparently fn is hardware only so it doesn't have hex value it only changes output value of F1,F2,F3... to get functions like mute, volume down, brightness up...

I tried using python script that prints out hex code of pressed keyboard button but it was wrong. Searched a lot of hid documentation and couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour] and read [ask]. Also please read  [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please learn how to create a [mre] of your own code, and how to [edit] your questions to improve them.